# Menu bug with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, menu, navigation

I'm having a bug with the menu I'm developing, it all goes well until you mouse over a child of the menu fast.

The bug is also different on Firefox and Chrome, I think its because one render faster than the other, in Firefox it becomes an infinite bug, in Chrome it last for a few seconds, then it disappears.

**Here's my html code:**

```
<div id="menu" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
            <label class="formatText" id="lblIndicators">Primer Menu</label>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e menuIcon" style="float:right"></span>
            <div id="subMenu" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
            <ul class="options">
                <li>
                    <label class="formatText">Sub Menu Uno</label>
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s" style="float:right"></span>
                    <div id="subMenuRight" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                        <ul class=options>
                            <li>Sub-Sub Menu Uno</li>
                            <li>Sub-Sub Menu Dos</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>Sub Menu Dos</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**Here's my JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize(){

    $("#menu").hover(mouseIn,mouseOut);
    $(".options li").hover(overOption,outOption);
    $("#subMenu").hover(openRightMenu,closeRightMenu);
}

function mouseIn(){
    $(this).find('span').attr('class','');
    $(this).find('span').attr('class','ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s');
    $("#subMenu").slideDown(100);
}

function mouseOut(){
    $(this).find('span').attr('class','');
    $(this).find('span').attr('class','ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e');
    $("#subMenu").fadeOut(100);
}

function overOption(){
    $(this).attr('class','ui-state-hover ui-corner-all');
}

function outOption(){
    $(this).attr('class','');
}

function openRightMenu(){
    $("#subMenuRight").slideDown(100);
}

function closeRightMenu(){
    $("#subMenuRight").slideUp(100);
}
```

[Here's a video of the bug](http://screencast.com/t/kfyIdUxi0r)

[Here's a live demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxvkN/23/)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop all animations before creating new ones so they don't go over each other. I added some .stop(true, true) methods for your to clear your queue. [**Have a look**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxvkN/27/) if that sorted your problem

```
    $(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize(){

    $("#menu").hover(mouseIn,mouseOut);
    $(".options li").hover(overOption,outOption);
    $("#subMenu").hover(openRightMenu,closeRightMenu);
}

function mouseIn(){
    $(this).find('span').attr('class','');
    $(this).find('span').attr('class','ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s');
    $("#subMenu").stop(true, true).slideDown(100);
}

function mouseOut(){
    $(this).find('span').attr('class','');
    $(this).find('span').attr('class','ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e');
    $("#subMenu").stop(true, true).fadeOut(100);
}

function overOption(){
    $(this).attr('class','ui-state-hover ui-corner-all');
}

function outOption(){
    $(this).attr('class','');
}

function openRightMenu(){
    $("#subMenuRight").stop(true, true).slideDown(100);
}

function closeRightMenu(){
    $("#subMenuRight").stop(true, true).slideUp(100);
}
```

Comment: You might want to provide a link to the particular version of the fiddle that you saved.

Comment: It worked but I have to remove the `stop(true, true)` from the `mouseOut` function of the hover, and let it only in the `mouseIn` and it works great, Thx!